# highcharts: bar/column chart with drilldown

Tags: highcharts, bar-chart

I know how to add a drilldown to a bar/column chart with only one series. I was wondering if it is possible to add a drilldown to a bar/column chart with multiple series?

Comment: You can check this demo from official API: http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/drilldown/multi-series/

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is. Just create a second series and have the points' `drilldown` ids inside the `drilldown []` array.